# What do I do about OTA upate notifications on my rooted Galaxy S7?

Tags: root-access, ota-update, samsung-galaxy-s7

I rooted my S7 using the Odin method found in this thread: http://forum.xda-developers.com/verizon-s7-edge/how-to/root-guide-verizon-s7-s7-edge-sm-g930v-t3411015

I'm getting daily popups on my phone for a system update. For now I just reschedule it for later. Does anybody know if this update will cause problems with my rooted device? Will I have to re-root?

Should I block the update, and if so, how?

Comment: Usually those updates should fail, if you have modified even a single bit on your system partition. It should rather annoy you with a warning about a modified system. My advise: don't install them, they may unroot your device or cause other things to fail (don't fix it, if it ain't broken)